# Transpose 1 column to a header

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have a table with 4 columns: tagid, TimeStamp, intvalue, and floatvalue.

The tagid has four different types of data: LineRun, ScrapRun, Speed, and Length.

Each tagid has a value in either the column intvalue or floatvalue.

I would like to transpose the tagid into header and insert its corresponding value that associated with it.

How would you do this?

I spent several hours trying to do it but no luck! [image]I know you guys are expert so be easy on me, I am new to SQL :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are just looking for a `case` expression:

```
select timestamp, 
       (case when tagid = 'linerun' then intvalue end) as linerun,
       (case when tagid = 'scraprun' then intvalue end) as scraprun,
       (case when tagid = 'speed' then floatvalue end) as speed,
       (case when tagid = 'length' then floatvalue end) as length
from t;
```

Typically, the goal would be to get one row per timestamp.  For that, use aggregation:

```
select timestamp, 
       max(case when tagid = 'linerun' then intvalue end) as linerun,
       max(case when tagid = 'scraprun' then intvalue end) as scraprun,
       max(case when tagid = 'speed' then floatvalue end) as speed,
       max(case when tagid = 'length' then floatvalue end) as length
from t
group by timestamp;
```

Comment: I got it!... Thank you Gordon. Exactly what I was looking for. You are awesome!